# How to git checkout a remote branch named the same as a directory?

Tags: git, branch

We have a remote branch named `deploy` for building and testing deploy scripts. Not surprisingly, the deploy scripts end up in a directory called `deploy`. Now that the directory `deploy` is in the branch `master`, when doing an initial clone it's cumbersome to actually check out that branch.

```
$ git clone bitbucket.org:/myplace/mything
$ cd mything
$ ls
deploy          extensions      installExtensions   src         tests
$ git branch -r | grep dep
  origin/deploy
$ git checkout deploy
$ git branch
* master
$ git checkout origin/deploy
Note: checking out 'origin/deploy'.

You are in 'detached HEAD' state. [SNIP]
```

At this point should I just create a local branch named `deploy` and set it to track the remote? Is there any syntax I can give git so it knows I want to checkout a remote branch, not a local path?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could simply create a new local branch that points to the remote branch using either of these commands (the latter will check it out immediately):

```
git branch deploy origin/deploy
git checkout -b deploy origin/deploy
```

This will however not set up the tracking functionality that happens when Git automatically creates a branch for a remote branch. To do that you have to do the following:

```
git branch -u origin/deploy
```

As an alternative, you can do this all in a single command, which is the same what Git would automatically do:

```
git checkout -b deploy --track origin/deploy
```

Comment: 'git checkout --track origin/deploy' works fine for me, I don't need the -b flag.

Answer (score 5):

My workaround for this is

`git checkout deploy --`